# ThisMember Composite object with recursive mapping

Tags: c#, datamapper

I have a question, I have a following object:

```
public class Category {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int MaxDepth { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> ChildrenNodes { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using NHibernate to retrieve the data for this, because my list is `LazyLoading`,
it should be remapped into `CategoryDTO` btw: for internal uses too.

This is how to the DTO looks like... *(for the example I didn't put everything inside)*

```
public class CategoryDTO {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryDTO Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<CategoryDTO> ChildrenNodes { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using ***[ThisMember](https://github.com/JulianR/ThisMember)*** here is the reference on it.

***`Btw thanks Julian great tool.`***

I'm using it with this extension method that I wrote.

```
 public static TOut Map<TIn, TOut>(this TIn source)
        where TIn : class
        where TOut : new() {
        return Mapper.Map<TIn, TOut>(source);
 }
```

*Now is the question:*

How to Map a Composite object with recursion?
I haven't found an answer for this within Julian examples.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

You can suggest other mappers but it must be `ThisMember` speed equivalent or faster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly easy:

```
var catDTO = new CategoryDTO {
  Title = "Parent",
  ChildrenNodes = new List<CategoryDTO> { new CategoryDTO { Title = "Child" }}
};            

var mapper = new MemberMapper();
mapper.CreateMap<CategoryDTO, Category>(category => new Category {
  ChildrenNodes = 
    category.ChildrenNodes == null ? null :
      category.ChildrenNodes.Select(c => mapper.Map<CategoryDTO, Category>(c)).ToList()
});

var mappedCategory = mapper.Map<CategoryDTO, Category>(catDTO);
```