# Convert complex Business object to ViewModel?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading, automapper, datamapper

I have a following object:

```
public class Category {
    public override long Id { get; set; }
    public override string Title { get; set; }
    public override int MaxDepth { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> ChildrenNodes { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using NHibernate to retrieve the data for this, because my list is `LazyLoading`,
it should be remapped into `CategoryViewModel` btw: for internal uses too.

This is how to the ViewModel looks like... *(for the example I didn't put everything inside)*

```
public class CategoryViewModel {
    public override long Id { get; set; }
    public override string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoryViewModel Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<CategoryViewModel> ChildrenNodes { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using it with this extension method that I wrote.

```
 public static TOut Map<TIn, TOut>(this TIn source)
        where TIn : class
        where TOut : new() {
        return Mapper.Map<TIn, TOut>(source); // ThiSMember
 }
```

*Now is the question:*

How to Map a Composite object with recursion? 
I haven't found an answer for this within ThisMemer examples.

Automapper has been failing because the NHibernate LazyLoading.

Can you please suggest other mappers ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ThisMember Composite object with recursive mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883387/thismember-composite-object-with-recursive-mapping)